# Create a counter that iterates over a column in a dataframe, and counts when a condition in the column is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a column in my dataframe called `step`, that I want to use to set a counter on. It contains a bunch of repeating numbers. I want to create a new column against this, that has a counter that increments when a certain condition is met. The condition is when the number changes for a fourth time in the column `step`, the counter will increment by 1, and then repeat the process. Here is an example of my code, and what I'd like to acheive:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"step": [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,7,7,
7,8,8,8,9,9,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,7]})

df['counter'] = df['step'].cumsum() #This will increment when it sees a fourth different number, and repeat
```

So ideally, my output would look like this:

```
print(df['step'])

[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,7,7,
7,8,8,8,9,9,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,7,7]

print(df['counter'])
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,
3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5]
```

The numbers in step will vary, but the counter will always increment when the fourth different value in the sequence is identified and reset the counter. I know I could probably do this with if statements, but my dataframe is large and I would rather do it in a faster way of comparison, if possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your `step` column into categories and then count on the category codes:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"step": [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10]})
df["counter"] = df.step.astype("category").values.codes // 3
```

Result:

```
    step  counter
0      1        0
1      1        0
2      1        0
3      2        0
4      2        0
5      2        0
6      2        0
7      3        0
8      3        0
9      3        0
10     4        1
11     4        1
12     4        1
13     5        1
14     5        1
15     5        1
16     5        1
17     6        1
18     6        1
19     6        1
20     7        2
21     7        2
22     7        2
23     7        2
24     8        2
25     8        2
26     8        2
27     8        2
28     8        2
29     9        2
30     9        2
31     9        2
32     9        2
33    10        3
```

---

Update for changed data (see comment):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"step": [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,7,7]})
df['counter'] = (df.step.diff().fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum() // 3).astype(int)
```

```
    step  counter
0      1        0
1      1        0
2      1        0
3      2        0
4      2        0
5      2        0
6      2        0
7      3        0
8      3        0
9      3        0
10     4        1
11     4        1
12     4        1
13     5        1
14     5        1
15     5        1
16     5        1
17     6        1
18     6        1
19     6        1
20     7        2
21     7        2
22     7        2
23     7        2
24     8        2
25     8        2
26     8        2
27     8        2
28     8        2
29     9        2
30     9        2
31     9        2
32     9        2
33     7        3
34     7        3
35     7        3
36     8        3
37     8        3
38     8        3
39     9        3
40     9        3
41     7        4
42     7        4
43     8        4
44     8        4
45     8        4
46     9        4
47     9        4
48     9        4
49     7        5
50     7        5
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I should have stated that the numbers can repeat (at some point, the numbers in step are merely `7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9` so I should have shown this in my example, as the counter would increment when it gets back to `7` (a fourth unique number). I will update my question to reflect this

Comment: @MurrayRoss please see my updated answer for this case

Comment: An addendum - if I wanted to start the counter at one, is this possible?

Comment: @MurrayRoss to have the counter start at one just add 1 to the result `...).astype(int) + 1`

Answer (score 1):

Compare the current and previous row in `step` column to identify boundaries(location of transitions), then use `cumsum` to assign number to groups of rows and floor divide by 3 to create counter

```
m = df.step != df.step.shift()
df['counter'] = (m.cumsum() - 1) // 3
```

---

```
    step  counter
0      1        0
1      1        0
2      1        0
3      2        0
4      2        0
5      2        0
6      2        0
7      3        0
8      3        0
9      3        0
10     4        1
11     4        1
12     4        1
13     5        1
14     5        1
15     5        1
16     5        1
17     6        1
18     6        1
19     6        1
20     7        2
21     7        2
22     7        2
23     7        2
24     8        2
25     8        2
26     8        2
27     8        2
28     8        2
29     9        2
30     9        2
31     9        2
32     9        2
33     7        3
34     7        3
35     7        3
36     8        3
37     8        3
38     8        3
39     9        3
40     9        3
41     7        4
42     7        4
43     8        4
44     8        4
45     8        4
46     9        4
47     9        4
48     9        4
49     7        5
```